# На ios-устройствах в любых браузерах не работают input

Tags: html, html5

Приветствую.
На моем сайте на любых IOS-устройствах не работают поля `input` и `textarea`, а именно не вводятся символы.

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="password"],
input[type~="text"],
input[type~="search"],
input[type~="password"],
input[type~="email"],
input.text,
input.search,
textarea,
input.file {
  font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.input-text {
  width: 270px;
  width: calc(100% - 5px - 7px);
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.mrgB-10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.bl {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="login" class="input-text bl mrgB-10" placeholder="Email">
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: я бы попробовал добавить атрибут name и атрибут value, собственно эти поля (input, textarea) предназначены для передачи данных с именем переменной Name и значением Value, может быть отсутствие этих основных полей и задаёт такое поведение.

Comment: @MaksimZlatov к сожалению, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
    -khtml-user-select: auto !important;
    -moz-user-select: auto !important;
    -ms-user-select: auto !important;
    -o-user-select: auto !important;
    user-select: auto !important;  
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]